# Can I have elements inside a pre?

Tags: css, escaping, pre

I want to change the `color` of a single piece of text inside a `<pre>`. But I do NOT want to change the `color` of the whole text

I am aware I can style the `<pre>` like:

```
pre{
    ...
}
```

But that will apply it to the entire text :(

Can I somehow escape a `<span>` and place it inside the `<pre>` so I can do something like:

```
pre span{
    ...
}
```

If not, what other options do I have?

Comment: Use inline styling using `<span>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I read i think you are looking for something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/3guQ7/

```css
pre span{
    color: green;        
}
```

```html
<div>
<pre>
    In not Green
    <span>Im green</span>
</pre>
<div>
```

Comment: I feel like a fool, I thought they escaped everything but it seems only code is escaped

Comment: @ajax333221 No worries, ajax. I thought I was an HTML CSS expert and I also made the ill assumption that the <pre> tag escaped everything, thus I am here asking instead of trying.